# Installing PDQ on windows

Tags: python, r, perl, modeling, capacity-planning

I am trying to install "pretty damn quick", an analysis tool for Layered Queing networks.

However there seems to be a lot wrong with my system, and switching to Linux is not an option.

Here is what i tried to get the PDQ running:

First try: Python

1. I installed python2.7 and downloaded the PDQ for python distribution (its in the tarball in the python dir) :

   C:\pdq\pdq42\python>python setup.py install
   running install
   running build
   running build_ext
   building 'pdq' extension
   error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

This error stems from the fact that i supposedly dont have a C-compiler. Even though typing g++ gives me:

```
C:\pdq\pdq42\python>g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw3
3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
```

...snipped...

1. This problem is somehow documented? So i tried going over to Perl. It said there that the compiler comes with Strawberry Perl. So I installed that. Dmake gave me a lot of trouble but in the end I managed to install it.

   C:\pdq\pdq42\perl5>perl Makefile.PL
   Writing Makefile for pdq

   C:\pdq\pdq42\perl5>dmake
   Skip blib\lib\pdq.pm (unchanged)
   ...snipped...

   g++.exe: error: MVA_Approx.o: No such file or directory
   g++.exe: error: MVA_Canon.o: No such file or directory
   g++.exe: error: MVA_Solve.o: No such file or directory
   g++.exe: error: PDQ_Build.o: No such file or directory
   g++.exe: error: PDQ_Exact.o: No such file or directory
   g++.exe: error: PDQ_Globals.o: No such file or directory
   g++.exe: error: PDQ_Report.o: No such file or directory
   g++.exe: error: PDQ_Utils.o: No such file or directory
   dmake:  Error code 129, while making 'blib\arch\auto\pdq\pdq.dll'

Gives me new errors, that i cannot fix, since i cannot google them.

1. As the last resort i try out installing R, since this should work according to the documentation.

   > install.packages("c:\pdq\pdq_6.0-1.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
   >   Warning: invalid package 'c:/pdq/pdq_6.0-1.tar.gz'
   >   Error: ERROR: no packages specified
   >   Warning messages:
   >   1: running command '"C:/Programme/R/R-3.0.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Programme\R\R-3.0.1\library" "c:/pdq/pdq_6.0-1.tar.gz"' had status 1 
   >   2: In install.packages("c:\pdq\pdq_6.0-1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
   >     installation of package ‘c:/pdq/pdq_6.0-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

However in this case i don't even know where to start debugging this to get it going. 
So I am seeking help from SO. My question is:

Where did I go wrong and what can I do to find additional information leading to identify the problem? I would really like to have PDQ installed.

Comment: If you want a C compiler, I believe you need to use `gcc`, not `g++`

Comment: Also it looks to me that the current tarball is pdq_6.1-1.tar.gz.  They should update their documentation but it is easy enough to fix.  So... change that line in your install.packages statement and see if that helps.  And you did install RTools right?

Comment: thanks for the help ! gcc is also installed. Rtools are installed. the line in my install.packages statement is copied from the filename, but will doublecheck that.

Comment: i cant believe it. I must have mistyped the name somehow. Now it works with R! I have been at this for hours. Thanks ! Pity it does not work with python though. Will have a hard time finding a graphical frontend that now.

Comment: can you put this into an answer, so i can close the question?