# How to install python packages in Microsoft Azure platform

Tags: python, azure

I have write a python script based on a linux version python package "pdq", the script works fine on local machine. But I am looking to upload the script to Azure platform. Since Azure environment dose not support "pdq" package, is there any way I could install the python package on the Azure platform and make my script works?

Comment: define "azure platform", where you want that exactly?

Comment: Right - web app? web/worker role? VM? Azure Platform is fairly massive in scope. As written, no way to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidMakogon said, your description is not clear, there is not any information about which azure service you used. I searched & reviewed some introduction about `pdq`, there is not any existing `pdq` wheels package which can be directly installed on Windows, and it's not offical supported on Windows. So whatever azure services like WebApps based on Windows, you could not simply install it via the `pip` command tool or `setup.py`.

If you have to install it on Azure WebApps/CloudService, you need to manually compile it via some Linux-Compatible compiler toolchain on Windows, such as [MinGW](http://mingw.org/). There was some people who had tried to compile `pdq` on Windows. you can try to refer to [Installing PDQ on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744253/installing-pdq-on-windows) to do it, although the trial seems not to be completed completely. Meanwhile, if you can compile it successfully on Windows, you need to refer to the Azure offical document of [Troubleshooting - Package Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure#troubleshooting---package-installation) for Python to build your own `pdq` wheels file for installing on Azure, because Azure not support compiling for C/C++ source code online.

The workaround ways for installing `pdq` is using Azure Linux VM to do it, or using Azure Container Service which also is a good choice.

Hope it helps.